# UITableview footer comes back after deselecting the last row

Tags: uitableview

I have successfully removed the colored separator at the bottom of my UITableView with:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 0.1f;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [UIView new];
    //[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
}
```

However when I deselect the last row, the footer gets drawn again.

How can I prevent the footer in my section 1 from ever being drawn please?